# How to hide os_log timestamp prepended in Xcode console?

Tags: swift, xcode, logging

When I change to log my messages from `print` to `os_log`, it indeed provided very detail timestamp for each message. But sometimes I does not need the long timestamp information occupied screen space.

How to hide/reformat the Xcode's console or could I configure `OSLog` to not show timestamp for a while? Or I should use print instead?

Here is my logger use

```
let logger = OSLog(subsystem: "com.my.myapp", category: "MediaObj")
os_log(.debug, log: logger, "....my...message...")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Xcode, is there a way to disable the timestamps that appear in the debugger console when calling NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354728/in-xcode-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-timestamps-that-appear-in-the-debugger-c)

Comment: @SagarChauhan `NSLog` and `OSLog` are different APIs. This isn't a dupe.

Comment: Was there any update on this?

Comment: I made a workaround that adding a control flag to decide 1) print to output window without timestamp using print (in debug), or 2) print to Console with full timestamp using os_log(.default, ...) (in release).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Logger` struct to log you logs, you can toggle timestamps (and other information) on and off as you see fit.

Apple has a bunch of good documentation on using `Logger` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).

You can use the `Logger` struct to log your logs. When you log your logs with the `Logger` you can filter logs and other cool stuff. Your logs will print without timestamps (although you can toggle them back on if you want to). You use it like this:

```swift
import os

let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.my.myapp", category: "MediaObj")
logger.info("....my...message...")
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to remove the timestamp. Your answer makes no attempt to describe how to do that.

Comment: @HangarRash Using the `Logger` allows you to toggle timestamps and other data from the console. This and the rest of the API are described in the link I added at the top.

Comment: For your answer to be helpful it should show how to solve the issue in the question. Currently your answer does not show how to turn off the timestamps. Update your answer to show how that is done and then you will have a good answer.

Comment: @HangarRash The answer does print without timestamps. I can add a screenshot if that would help.

Comment: Sure, adding a screenshot would help. But more importantly, your answer should at least mention that using the code you posted results in log message with no timestamps. It's not clear at all from your answer that it results in no timestamps.

Comment: Never actually found the answer to this, even following the linked docs.  Did anybody ACTUALLY solve this?